# how to reduce the Procedure time in oracle which is running based on Cursor for loop?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

How can I reduce the time of the procedure? Now it is taking 7 minutes to completed, I am using Cursor for loop in my report to loop around the 400 employees (using Cursor for loop) for 30 days (Looping the dates using While loop) in a month including absent or Present calculations, Now I want to reduce the time of completing the report Output
my oracle version is 11g R2 and OS is Windows 7 or Windows 2008 server.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_SAPABSENTRPT
( 
  "P_FROMDATE" IN DATE,  "P_TODATE" IN DATE,  "GRADE" IN NUMBER,  "EMPID" IN NUMBER,  "DEPTID" IN NUMBER,  CUR_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS

EMPIDCNT NUMBER; EMPNO VARCHAR2(100); NOOFDAYS NUMBER:=0;DAYS NUMBER;V_CNTEMPSYSIDFN NUMBER;V_EMPID NUMBER;
V_LOOP  NUMBER := 1;CNTSYSID NUMBER;V_DATEOFAB VARCHAR2(30);V_CNTEMPSYSID NUMBER;V_CNTEMPSYSIDAN NUMBER; V_COUNT NUMBER;
FROM_DATE DATE;V_FIRSTHALFPRESENT NUMBER;V_SECONDHALFPRESENT NUMBER;V_CNT NUMBER;V_FULLDAYPRESENT NUMBER;V_PRVSDAYCNT NUMBER;
V_STARTTIME VARCHAR2(20);V_ENDTIME VARCHAR2(20);V_BREAKOUT VARCHAR2(20);V_BREAKIN VARCHAR2(20);V_EARTLYTIME VARCHAR2(20);V_LEAVETYPE VARCHAR2(20);
V_EARLTYCNT NUMBER;V_PRESENTEMPCNT NUMBER;V_EMPNO NUMBER;V_FULLDAYLEAVE NUMBER;V_FULLDAYOOD NUMBER;V_LEAVECNT NUMBER;V_OODCNT NUMBER;
V_FHLVSHPRESENT NUMBER;V_SHLVFHPRESENT NUMBER;V_FIRSTHALFOOD NUMBER;V_SECONDHALFOOD NUMBER;V_FHLVSHOOD NUMBER;V_SHLVFHOOD NUMBER;
V_FHOODSHLV NUMBER;V_SHOODFHLV NUMBER;V_FHLVSHABSENT NUMBER;V_FHOODSHABSENT NUMBER;V_SHLVFHABSENT NUMBER;V_SHOODFHABSENT NUMBER;V_TBLCNT NUMBER;
V_STWEEKDAY VARCHAR2(10);V_HOLIDAYCNT NUMBER;V_GRADECODE VARCHAR2(20);V_SHIFTCNT NUMBER;V_STALLTENDATE DATE;V_SUNDAYCNT NUMBER;
V_NXTDAYFULL_LVCNT NUMBER;V_NXTDAYSN_LVCNT NUMBER;V_NEXTDAY_SCHLABS NUMBER;V_STARTTIME1 VARCHAR2(20);V_BREAKOUT1 VARCHAR2(20);
V_FIRSTHALFPRESENT1 NUMBER;V_FLDAYHLDAY VARCHAR2(6);V_NEXTDAY_FSHLABS NUMBER;V_NEXTDAY_FULLABS NUMBER;V_NXTDAYFULL_OODCNT NUMBER;

CURSOR C_EMPID IS

SELECT E.SYSID FROM EMPLOYEE E,GRADE G,DEPARTMENT D
WHERE E.GRADE_SYSID=G.SYSID AND G.SYSID=DECODE(SP_SAPABSENTRPT.GRADE ,0,G.SYSID,SP_SAPABSENTRPT.GRADE)
AND E.DEPARTMENT_SYSID=D.SYSID AND  D.SYSID= DECODE(SP_SAPABSENTRPT.DEPTID ,0,D.SYSID,SP_SAPABSENTRPT.DEPTID )
AND E.SYSID=DECODE(SP_SAPABSENTRPT.EMPID,0,E.SYSID,SP_SAPABSENTRPT.EMPID) AND E.GRADE_SYSID NOT IN (325,326) ORDER BY E.SYSID;
--The Grades E8 and E9 not included in this report as per Rakesh (BHEL Employee) email on May 30 2013 2:06 PM  

begin

    DELETE FROM TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT;
  --DELETE FROM TMPEMPIDS;
  COMMIT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'));
  OPEN C_EMPID;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_EMPID INTO V_EMPID;
    EXIT WHEN C_EMPID%NOTFOUND;

      --for r_rec in c_rec loop
      FROM_DATE:=TRIM(P_FROMDATE);

        WHILE NOT TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') > TO_DATE(P_TODATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')
           LOOP --Looping the dates from given start and end date

      --********************************************************************************************************************
       SELECT EMPNO INTO V_EMPNO FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE SYSID=V_EMPID;

              SELECT G.CODE INTO V_GRADECODE FROM GRADE G,EMPLOYEE E
              WHERE E.GRADE_SYSID=G.SYSID AND E.SYSID=V_EMPID;              


           --Getting shift timings from Shiftallotment table if shift not available else will go for EG General Shift 
            SELECT COUNT(SYSID) INTO V_SHIFTCNT FROM SHIFTSALLOTMENT
            WHERE TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') AND EMPNO=V_EMPNO;

           IF(V_SHIFTCNT=0) THEN --IF no shift allotted for the date alloing EG shift

              SELECT last_day(add_months(sysdate,12 - to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mm')))) INTO V_STALLTENDATE from dual;

              INORUP_SHIFTSALLOTMENT_PROC(0,0,V_EMPID,201,FROM_DATE,V_STALLTENDATE,101);

           END IF;

          IF(V_SHIFTCNT!=0) THEN --Shift IF Open

             SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY'),'DY') INTO V_STWEEKDAY FROM DUAL;

             IF(V_STWEEKDAY!='SAT') THEN --Validating the week is not sunday get the results from the starting week from previous month.

                SELECT S.STARTTIME,S.ENDTIME,S.BREAKOUT,S.BREAKIN INTO V_STARTTIME,V_ENDTIME,V_BREAKOUT,V_BREAKIN
                FROM SHIFTS S,SHIFTSALLOTMENT SA WHERE S.SYSID=SA.SHIFTID AND SA.EMPNO=V_EMPNO
                AND TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY');

             ELSE

                SELECT S.SATURDAYSTART INTO V_STARTTIME
                FROM SHIFTS S,SHIFTSALLOTMENT SA WHERE S.SYSID=SA.SHIFTID AND SA.EMPNO=V_EMPNO 
                AND TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY');

               IF(V_STARTTIME IS NOT NULL) THEN --IF no shift on saturday then select weekday shift only

                  SELECT S.SATURDAYSTART,S.SATURDAYEND,S.SATURDAYLUNCHSTART,S.SATURDAYLUNCHEND
                  INTO V_STARTTIME,V_ENDTIME,V_BREAKOUT,V_BREAKIN FROM SHIFTS S,SHIFTSALLOTMENT SA 
                  WHERE S.SYSID=SA.SHIFTID AND SA.EMPNO=V_EMPNO AND TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY');

               ELSE

                  SELECT S.STARTTIME,S.ENDTIME,S.BREAKOUT,S.BREAKIN INTO V_STARTTIME,V_ENDTIME,V_BREAKOUT,V_BREAKIN
                  FROM SHIFTS S,SHIFTSALLOTMENT SA WHERE S.SYSID=SA.SHIFTID AND SA.EMPNO=V_EMPNO
                  AND TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY');               

               END IF;

             END IF;          
          END IF; --End Shift IF


              IF(V_GRADECODE LIKE 'E%' OR V_GRADECODE LIKE 'S%' OR V_GRADECODE='FTA') THEN

                  V_STARTTIME:=ADDHOURS_FUN(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_STARTTIME,'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('00:30','HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI'));
              ELSE
                  V_STARTTIME:=ADDHOURS_FUN(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_STARTTIME,'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01:00','HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI'));
              END IF;

              V_EARTLYTIME:=HOURSDIFFERENCEFUN_FUN(to_char(to_date(V_ENDTIME,'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('02:00','HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI'));              


              SELECT COUNT(L.SYSID) INTO V_LEAVECNT FROM LEAVEFORMENTRY L WHERE L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.ACTIVE='1';

              SELECT COUNT(L.SYSID) INTO V_CNT FROM LEAVETYPE LT,LEAVEFORMENTRY L
              WHERE LT.SYSID=L.LEAVETYPE AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.ACTIVE='1';

              IF(V_CNT!=0) THEN

                  SELECT LT.LEAVETYPE INTO V_LEAVETYPE FROM LEAVETYPE LT,LEAVEFORMENTRY L
                  WHERE LT.SYSID=L.LEAVETYPE AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO 
                  AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
                  AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.ACTIVE='1';

              END IF;

              SELECT COUNT(O.SYSID) INTO V_OODCNT FROM OODENTRY O WHERE O.EMPID=V_EMPID 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND O.ACTIVE=1 ; 

              --First halfs
              SELECT COUNT(SYSID) INTO V_FIRSTHALFPRESENT FROM ATTENDENCELOG
              WHERE TO_DATE(DATERECORDED,'DD-MM-YYYY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND EMPLOYEE_SYSID=V_EMPID
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(INTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI') <= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_STARTTIME, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI')
              AND  to_char(to_date(OUTTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI')  >= to_char(to_date(V_BREAKOUT, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(
              SELECT (E1.SYSID) FROM LEAVEFORMENTRY L,EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE L.EMPNO=E1.EMPNO 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO AND L.ACTIVE='1' AND L.FNTYPE='FN')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(SELECT E2.SYSID FROM OODENTRY O, EMPLOYEE E2 WHERE O.EMPID=E2.SYSID 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.TODATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') AND O.EMPID=V_EMPID AND O.ACTIVE=1 AND O.DAYTYPE='FN');              

              --Second Halfs
              SELECT COUNT(SYSID) INTO V_SECONDHALFPRESENT FROM ATTENDENCELOG
              WHERE TO_DATE(DATERECORDED,'DD-MM-YYYY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND EMPLOYEE_SYSID=V_EMPID
              AND (to_char(to_date(INTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI') <= to_char(to_date(V_BREAKIN, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI') 
              OR to_char(to_date(INTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI') >= to_char(to_date(V_BREAKIN, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI'))
              AND  to_char(to_date(OUTTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI')  >= to_char(to_date(V_ENDTIME, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(
              SELECT (E1.SYSID) FROM LEAVEFORMENTRY L,EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE L.EMPNO=E1.EMPNO 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO AND L.ACTIVE='1' AND L.FNTYPE='AN')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(SELECT E2.SYSID FROM OODENTRY O, EMPLOYEE E2 WHERE O.EMPID=E2.SYSID 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.TODATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') AND O.EMPID=V_EMPID AND O.ACTIVE=1 AND O.DAYTYPE='AN');

        --********************************************************************************************************************             
              SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_PRVSDAYCNT FROM TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT WHERE EMPID=V_EMPID AND FROM_DATE-1 BETWEEN ABSENTFROM AND ABSENTTO;
              SELECT COUNT(SYSID) INTO V_HOLIDAYCNT FROM HOLIDAY WHERE TO_DATE(HOLIDAYDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-YY');              
              SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_SUNDAYCNT FROM DUAL WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY'),'DY')='SUN';

              SELECT COUNT(L.SYSID) INTO V_NXTDAYFULL_LVCNT FROM LEAVEFORMENTRY L,EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE L.EMPNO=E1.EMPNO AND L.ACTIVE='1'
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')+1 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') AND L.FNTYPE='FULL' AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO;

              SELECT COUNT(E1.SYSID) INTO V_NXTDAYFULL_OODCNT FROM OODENTRY O,EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE O.EMPID=E1.SYSID AND O.ACTIVE='1'
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')+1 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.FROMDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.TODATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') AND O.DAYTYPE='FULL' AND O.EMPID=V_EMPID;

            SELECT COUNT(SYSID) INTO V_SHIFTCNT FROM SHIFTSALLOTMENT
            WHERE TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1 AND EMPNO=V_EMPNO;

            IF(V_SHIFTCNT!=0) THEN --Shift IF Open

             SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1,'DY') INTO V_STWEEKDAY FROM DUAL;

             IF(V_STWEEKDAY!='SAT') THEN --Validating the week is not sunday get the results from the starting week from previous month.

                SELECT S.STARTTIME,S.BREAKOUT INTO V_STARTTIME1,V_BREAKOUT1
                FROM SHIFTS S,SHIFTSALLOTMENT SA WHERE S.SYSID=SA.SHIFTID AND SA.EMPNO=V_EMPNO
                AND TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1;

             ELSE

                SELECT S.SATURDAYSTART INTO V_STARTTIME1
                FROM SHIFTS S,SHIFTSALLOTMENT SA WHERE S.SYSID=SA.SHIFTID AND SA.EMPNO=V_EMPNO 
                AND TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1;

               IF(V_STARTTIME IS NOT NULL) THEN --IF no shift on saturday then select weekday shift only

                  SELECT S.SATURDAYSTART,S.SATURDAYLUNCHSTART
                  INTO V_STARTTIME1,V_BREAKOUT1 FROM SHIFTS S,SHIFTSALLOTMENT SA 
                  WHERE S.SYSID=SA.SHIFTID AND SA.EMPNO=V_EMPNO AND TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1;

               ELSE

                  SELECT S.STARTTIME,S.BREAKOUT INTO V_STARTTIME1,V_BREAKOUT1
                  FROM SHIFTS S,SHIFTSALLOTMENT SA WHERE S.SYSID=SA.SHIFTID AND SA.EMPNO=V_EMPNO
                  AND TO_DATE(SHIFTDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1;

               END IF;

             END IF;          
          END IF; --End Shift IF


              IF(V_GRADECODE LIKE 'E%' OR V_GRADECODE LIKE 'S%' OR V_GRADECODE='FTA') THEN

                  V_STARTTIME1:=ADDHOURS_FUN(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_STARTTIME1,'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('00:30','HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI'));
              ELSE
                  V_STARTTIME1:=ADDHOURS_FUN(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_STARTTIME1,'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01:00','HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI'));
              END IF;


              SELECT COUNT(SYSID) INTO V_NEXTDAY_SCHLABS FROM ATTENDENCELOG
              WHERE TO_DATE(DATERECORDED,'DD-MM-YYYY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')+1 AND EMPLOYEE_SYSID=V_EMPID
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(INTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI') <= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_STARTTIME1, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI')
              AND  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OUTTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI')  >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_BREAKOUT1, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(
              SELECT (E1.SYSID) FROM LEAVEFORMENTRY L,EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE L.EMPNO=E1.EMPNO 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO AND L.ACTIVE='1' AND L.FNTYPE='FN')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(SELECT E2.SYSID FROM OODENTRY O, EMPLOYEE E2 WHERE O.EMPID=E2.SYSID 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.TODATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') AND O.EMPID=V_EMPID AND O.ACTIVE=1 AND O.DAYTYPE='FN');

              SELECT COUNT(E.SYSID) INTO V_NEXTDAY_FULLABS FROM EMPLOYEE E
              WHERE V_EMPID NOT IN (SELECT EMPLOYEE_SYSID FROM ATTENDENCELOG
              WHERE TO_DATE(DATERECORDED,'DD-MM-YYYY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')+1 AND EMPLOYEE_SYSID=V_EMPID)
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(
              SELECT (E1.SYSID) FROM LEAVEFORMENTRY L,EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE L.EMPNO=E1.EMPNO 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO AND L.ACTIVE='1')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(SELECT E2.SYSID FROM OODENTRY O, EMPLOYEE E2 WHERE O.EMPID=E2.SYSID 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')+1 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.TODATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') AND O.EMPID=V_EMPID AND O.ACTIVE=1);

              SELECT COUNT(SYSID) INTO V_NEXTDAY_FSHLABS FROM ATTENDENCELOG
              WHERE TO_DATE(DATERECORDED,'DD-MM-YYYY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND EMPLOYEE_SYSID=V_EMPID
              AND (to_char(to_date(INTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI') <= to_char(to_date(V_BREAKIN, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI') 
              OR to_char(to_date(INTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI') >= to_char(to_date(V_BREAKIN, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI'))
              AND  to_char(to_date(OUTTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI')  >= to_char(to_date(V_ENDTIME, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(
              SELECT (E1.SYSID) FROM LEAVEFORMENTRY L,EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE L.EMPNO=E1.EMPNO 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO AND L.ACTIVE='1' AND L.FNTYPE='AN')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(SELECT E2.SYSID FROM OODENTRY O, EMPLOYEE E2 WHERE O.EMPID=E2.SYSID 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.TODATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') AND O.EMPID=V_EMPID AND O.ACTIVE=1 AND O.DAYTYPE='AN');

          IF(V_PRVSDAYCNT!=0 AND (V_HOLIDAYCNT!=0 OR V_SUNDAYCNT!=0) AND (V_NEXTDAY_FULLABS!=0 OR V_NEXTDAY_FSHLABS!=0) AND V_NEXTDAY_SCHLABS=0
              AND V_NXTDAYFULL_OODCNT=0 AND V_NXTDAYFULL_LVCNT=0) THEN --Verifyinng Previous day is Absent or not

             SELECT COUNT(ATTENDENCELOG.SYSID) INTO V_CNTEMPSYSID FROM ATTENDENCELOG,TBLDASHBOARD TBL
              WHERE TO_DATE(DATERECORDED,'DD-MM-YYYY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND ATTENDENCELOG.EMPLOYEE_SYSID=V_EMPID
              AND TBL.ATTENDENCELOG_SYSID=ATTENDENCELOG.SYSID
              AND (to_char(to_date(INTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI') <= to_char(to_date(V_STARTTIME, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI') 
              OR TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(INTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI') >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_STARTTIME, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI'))
              AND (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(OUTTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI')  >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_ENDTIME, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI')
              OR ((((TBL.RC1='P' AND TBL.IN2 IS NULL) OR (TBL.RC2='P' AND TBL.IN3 IS NULL )  OR (TBL.RC3='P' AND TBL.IN4 IS NULL) OR (TBL.RC4='P' AND TBL.IN5 IS NULL)  OR (TBL.RC5='P' AND TBL.IN6 IS NULL) OR TBL.RC6='P'))  OR ( (TBL.RC1='O' AND TBL.IN2 IS NULL) OR (TBL.RC2='O' AND TBL.IN3 IS NULL)   OR (TBL.RC3='O' AND TBL.IN4 IS NULL) OR (TBL.RC4='O'AND TBL.IN5 IS NULL) 
                    OR (TBL.RC5='O'AND TBL.IN6 IS NULL) OR TBL.RC6='O')))  AND V_EMPID NOT IN(
              SELECT (E1.SYSID) FROM LEAVEFORMENTRY L,EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE L.EMPNO=E1.EMPNO 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO AND L.ACTIVE='1')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(SELECT E2.SYSID FROM OODENTRY O, EMPLOYEE E2 WHERE O.EMPID=E2.SYSID 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.TODATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') AND O.EMPID=V_EMPID AND O.ACTIVE=1)
              AND (TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-YY') NOT IN (SELECT TO_CHAR(HOLIDAYDATE,'DD-MON-YY') FROM HOLIDAY)
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'DY')='SUN');--Defalut sunday is Holiday; 

          END IF; --Calculating Previous day END IF       

              SELECT COUNT(TO_NUMBER(EMPID)) INTO EMPIDCNT FROM TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT WHERE EMPID=V_EMPID AND FULLAN IS NULL;

              IF(EMPIDCNT!=0) THEN
                SELECT FULLAN INTO V_FLDAYHLDAY FROM (SELECT FULLAN FROM TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT WHERE EMPID=V_EMPID ORDER BY ABSENTTO DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <=1;
              END IF;
              --Previous is day Second half if is present or absent
              SELECT COUNT(SYSID) INTO V_FIRSTHALFPRESENT1 FROM ATTENDENCELOG
              WHERE TO_DATE(DATERECORDED,'DD-MM-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')-1 AND EMPLOYEE_SYSID=V_EMPID
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(INTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI') <= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(V_STARTTIME, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI')
              AND  to_char(to_date(OUTTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI')  >= to_char(to_date(V_BREAKOUT, 'HH:MI PM'),'HH24:MI')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(
              SELECT (E1.SYSID) FROM LEAVEFORMENTRY L,EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE L.EMPNO=E1.EMPNO 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')-1 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.TODATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') AND L.EMPNO=V_EMPNO AND L.ACTIVE='1' AND L.FNTYPE='FN')
              AND V_EMPID NOT IN(SELECT E2.SYSID FROM OODENTRY O, EMPLOYEE E2 WHERE O.EMPID=E2.SYSID 
              AND TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')-1 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
              AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(O.TODATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') AND O.EMPID=V_EMPID AND O.ACTIVE=1 AND O.DAYTYPE='FN');

           IF(EMPIDCNT>0 AND V_CNTEMPSYSID=0 AND V_CNTEMPSYSIDFN=0 AND V_CNTEMPSYSIDAN=0 AND V_HOLIDAYCNT=0
           AND V_FULLDAYLEAVE=0 AND V_FULLDAYOOD=0) THEN

              SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(ABSENTTO,'DD-MON-YY'))+1 INTO V_DATEOFAB FROM TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT WHERE EMPID=V_EMPID;

              IF(V_DATEOFAB=TRIM(FROM_DATE) AND (V_FIRSTHALFPRESENT=0 AND V_SECONDHALFPRESENT=0
                AND V_SHLVFHABSENT=0 AND V_FHLVSHABSENT=0 AND V_FHOODSHABSENT=0 AND V_SHOODFHABSENT=0) AND V_FLDAYHLDAY IS NULL) THEN

                  UPDATE TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT T SET T.ABSENTTO=FROM_DATE WHERE T.EMPID=V_EMPID AND
                  TO_DATE(ABSENTTO,'DD-MON-YY')=(SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(ABSENTTO,'DD-MON-YY')) FROM TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT WHERE EMPID=V_EMPID);
              ELSE
                      -------------------------------------                    

                        IF(V_PRESENTEMPCNT!=0 AND V_FULLDAYPRESENT=0) THEN --First IF open

                           INSERT INTO TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT(EMPID,DATEOFAB,STATUS,ABSENTFROM,ABSENTTO,EMPNO,FULLAN)       

                           SELECT (EMPLOYEE.SYSID),FROM_DATE,
                           CASE                                    
                           WHEN V_FIRSTHALFPRESENT!=0 THEN 'S'
                           WHEN V_SECONDHALFPRESENT!=0 THEN 'F'                   
                           ELSE 'FULL' END STATUS,FROM_DATE,FROM_DATE,(EMPLOYEE.EMPNO)EMPNO,
                           CASE                                    
                           WHEN V_FIRSTHALFPRESENT!=0 THEN 'S'
                           WHEN V_SECONDHALFPRESENT!=0 THEN 'F' END OODTYPE
                           FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNO=V_EMPNO;                     

                      ELSE --ELSE for First IF and EMPID not in TBLDASHBOARD then EMP in Leave or OOD or Absent 

                          IF(V_PRESENTEMPCNT=0 AND V_LEAVECNT=0 AND V_OODCNT=0) THEN --Absent

                              INSERT INTO TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT(EMPID,DATEOFAB,STATUS,ABSENTFROM,ABSENTTO,EMPNO,FULLAN)

                              SELECT (EMPLOYEE.SYSID),FROM_DATE,'FULL'STATUS,FROM_DATE,FROM_DATE,(EMPLOYEE.EMPNO)EMPNO,NULL                               
                              FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNO=V_EMPNO
                              AND FROM_DATE NOT IN (SELECT HOLIDAYDATE FROM HOLIDAY WHERE 
                              TO_DATE(HOLIDAYDATE,'DD-MON-YY')=TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'))
                              AND V_SUNDAYCNT=0;                                                          
                          END IF;
                      END IF;
              END IF;   
           END IF;
      COMMIT;
    FROM_DATE:=FROM_DATE+1; --Increasing the date upto TODATE
    END LOOP; --While Date loop End    
    --end loop;
    COMMIT;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C_EMPID;
END;
```

Comment: how about not using a cursor?

Comment: I have also used While Loop instead of Cursor loop still the procedure takes same time no change

Comment: Dude! Post it! Just change tables'/columns' names and you are done.

Comment: Using cursors, particularly nested cursors, is a cause of many performance problems. As Mitch implies, using a single query is going to give better performance. Maybe you need help with a query component that generates a list of 30 days as part of that, but if you post the code we can try to help.

Comment: try to make all calculations direct in SQL query

Comment: I have deleted part of the code because in Question page it is allowing only 30000 characters

Comment: This is a mess -- you convert between dates and char's everywhere. "TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(L.FROMDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')" -- that won't even work correctly because you're trying to compare a column that you're converted to a date (is it not a date already?) to a column that you've converted from either date or character (who knows?) to a date using MM-DD-YYYY and then back to a character string using 'DD-MON-YY' which can't be compared using BETWEEN, >, or < (the string "20-JAN-2001" sorts higher than the string "01-MAR-13"). Sort that stuff out first.

Comment: Ugh, there's just all sorts of ugly stuff in there. The whole methodology is wrong. I feel like you're breaking this down into the smallest possible unit, when you should be trying to combine code to make fewer steps. Example ... your initial cursor selects only the employee.sysid, so then inside the cursor you have to query to get employee.empno and grade.code -- they should have been selected in the cursor. Sorry, but it reads like a handbook of bad coding practice, and I'm afraid you have a lot of cleanup to do before this can be simplified to a reasonable degree.

Comment: Another one: "SELECT last_day(add_months(sysdate,12 - to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mm')))) INTO V_STALLTENDATE from dual" This returns December 31st of the current year with the same time as it is at the moment. You probably want: "V_STALLTENDATE := add_months(trunc(sysdate,'yyyy'),12)-1;". And do not do it for every row in the cursor! Do it once, and don't assign values to variables by querying from dual.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is completely unreadable. You've dumped a huge amount of code and haven't even bothered to format it correctly... I get the feeling that the vast majority of this can be done in a single , simpler, SQL statement but there's nothing we can do to help at the moment. We've no idea of the size of your tables, their relationships etc.

Comment: The first step in performance tuning is to identify what needs to be tuned.  The easiest way to do this in a procedure is to use [DBMS_PROFILER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_profil.htm).  If you're using a decent IDE, like PL/SQL Developer, there is even a GUI that will let you quickly visualize how much time is spent on which line.

Answer (score 1):

Few simple examples how to improve it. I do not think it will be enough.

```
1) small change
a)

from:
    DELETE FROM TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT;
  --DELETE FROM TMPEMPIDS;
    COMMIT;
to:
    /*TRUNCATE TABLE TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT; Pointed out by Ben */
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT';
b)

IF(V_PRESENTEMPCNT!=0 AND V_FULLDAYPRESENT=0) THEN --First IF open
    INSERT INTO TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT(EMPID,DATEOFAB,STATUS,ABSENTFROM,ABSENTTO,EMPNO,FULLAN)       
ELSE --ELSE for First IF and EMPID not in TBLDASHBOARD then EMP in Leave or OOD or Absent 
    IF(V_PRESENTEMPCNT=0 AND V_LEAVECNT=0 AND V_OODCNT=0) THEN --Absent
        INSERT INTO TEMPSAP_EMPLOGABSENT(EMPID,DATEOFAB,STATUS,ABSENTFROM,ABSENTTO,EMPNO,FULLAN)
    END IF;
END IF;

COMMIT; --- <---- add commit

2) medium change

from:
OPEN C_EMPID;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_EMPID INTO V_EMPID;
    EXIT WHEN C_EMPID%NOTFOUND;

to:
    OPEN C_EMPID;
    OPEN C_EMPID BULK COLLECT INTO V_EMPID; -- create it as nested table type
    OPEN C_EMPID;

    FOR indx IN 1..V_EMPID.COUNT LOOP
    ...

    -- exmaple use:
    SELECT EMPNO INTO V_EMPNO FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE SYSID=V_EMPID(indx);

3) huge change

With collections you can read all data at once and that work with it but that require some experience
from:
       SELECT EMPNO INTO V_EMPNO FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE SYSID=V_EMPID;

              SELECT G.CODE INTO V_GRADECODE FROM GRADE G,EMPLOYEE E
              WHERE E.GRADE_SYSID=G.SYSID AND E.SYSID=V_EMPID;        
to:


        SELECT EMPNO BULK COLLECT INTO V_EMPNO FROM EMPLOYEE /*WHERE SYSID=V_EMPID;*/ -- create it as nested table type

              SELECT G.CODE BULK COLLECT INTO V_GRADECODE FROM GRADE G,EMPLOYEE E -- create it as nested table type
              WHERE E.GRADE_SYSID=G.SYSID /*AND E.SYSID=V_EMPID;*/
```

Comment: TRUNCATE is DDL and therefore cannot be performed in PL/SQL unless done dynamically.

Comment: Committing inside the cursor is not going to be a good idea. Increased risk of a snapshot too old error, and worse performance.

Comment: It is committing the INSERT statement. There will be no read consistency.

Comment: "There will be no read consistency"? Don't follow what you mean there.

Comment: snapshot too old can occur when update/delete/... statements are committed.

Comment: there should be no commit.. you should only commit logical/consistent bits.. not just every row..